# Remove AppBar but keeping StatusBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How I can have a custom color for my StatusBar without the AppBar?

To customize the StatusBar color I used this code:

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal
)
```

If I remove `appbar` I can't customize the StatusBar. How I can do this?

How can I remove the AppBar but keeping the StatusBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `main.dart`'s main method file after the `runApp` method

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
        SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: <YOUR STATUS BAR COLOR>));
```

Like this:

```
void main(){
 runApp(MyApp());
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
            SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: <YOUR STATUS BAR COLOR>));
}
```

If you are using `SafeArea` then you need to set it's `top` property to `false`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming. In my case it was not working so I added that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     color: Your Color Here,
     child: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Scaffold(
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for change the status bar color first step you have  to import this package given below

"`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

and then add this code in your main.dart file

```
void main(){SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor:Colors.blue,));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can implemet using `AppBar`, in below code `backgroundColor: Colors.green` is applied to statusbar.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    elevation: 0,
    toolbarHeight: 0,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
  body: Container(),
)
```

Prview:

[image]